# Ionic View app not calling webservice

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I'm using the [Ionic View](http://view.ionic.io/) app to test my application. For the majority of the development on the app I've been testing and debugging in the browser using `ionic serve` . The app makes use of webservices that gets called just fine running the app in the browser.

However I'm trying to run the app now on Ionic View and the webservices aren't getting called, even though this was working a few weeks ago. The URL's and everything. Nothing has changed. I can see the web service isn't getting hit server side.

Has anybody had the same issue before?

**Update:**

It doesn't work on the PhoneGap developer app either. I've also added the [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) .

Comment: Can you provide some log when the error occur? Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2))` to see what exactly happened?

Comment: Did you also configure the `cordova-plugin-whitelist` plugin with a meta tag?